# Concatenating strings in a batch file

Tags: batch-file

In the batch file below I expect "C:\test Ground\" as the output

```
set loc= C:\test Ground\

set withQuotes="%loc%"
```

But what I get is " C:\test Ground\" (notice the extra leading space after the quotes begin)

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just get rid of the space between the `=` and the `C` on the first line:

```
set loc=C:\test Ground\
```

If that's not an option, you can extract the remainder of the string without the space using batch's substring functionality:

```
set withQuotes="%loc~1%"
```

Comment: That fixed it! I will mark it as the answer as soon as it lets me